# Zipping tuples and unpacking into same dimension

Tags: python

Given two lists

```
A = ['a','b','c','d']
B = [(1,11),(2,22),(3,33),(4,44)]
```

I want to zip into the list `[('a', 1, 11), ('b', 2, 22), ('c', 3, 33), ('d', 4, 44)]`.

Doing `list(zip(a, b))` gives `[('a', (1, 11)), ('b', (2, 22)), ('c', (3, 33)), ('d', (4, 44))]`.

Unpacking B doesn't work `[('a', 1, 2, 3, 4), ('b', 11, 22, 33, 44)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With python3.6, you can zip them and use the unpacking operator:

```
>>> [(a, *b) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
[('a', 1, 11), ('b', 2, 22), ('c', 3, 33), ('d', 4, 44)]
```

For older versions, perform tuple concatenation...

```
>>> [(a, ) + b for a, b in zip(A, B)]
[('a', 1, 11), ('b', 2, 22), ('c', 3, 33), ('d', 4, 44)]
```

...to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Or try `map`:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x,y: (x,)+y,A,B))
[('a', 1, 11), ('b', 2, 22), ('c', 3, 33), ('d', 4, 44)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although coldspeed's answer is much better, here is my 2 cents

```
l = [(z[0], z[1][0], z[1][1]) for z in zip (A, B)]
print(l)
```